# How to draw boxplot by multiple groups using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to get a boxplot with the following specifications for the following variables:
`assets, liability`.

My data is firms financial statement and firms are classified big and small firms (categorical variable `lbg30`). Time (years) is also categorized by two period pre-crisis and post-crisis (categorical variable `postcrisis`). So I want to draw boxplots of assets and liability for small firms vs big firms and also pre-crisis vs post-crisis.

```
structure(list(firmid = structure(c("000020", "000020", "000020", 
"000020", "000020", "000020", "000021", "000021", "000020", "000021"
), label = "거래소코드", format.stata = "%9s"), year = structure(c(1991, 
1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    postcrisis = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    firm_kor = structure(c("동화약품(주)", "동화약품(주)", 
    "동화약품(주)", "동화약품(주)", "동화약품(주)", 
    "동화약품(주)", "동화약(주)", "동화약(주)", 
    "동화약품(주)", "동화약(주)"), label = "회사명", format.stata = "%44s"), 
    business_group = structure(c("동화약", "동화약", "동화약", 
    "동화약", "동화약", "동화약", "동화약", "동화약", 
    "동화약", "동화약"), label = "그룹사명", format.stata = "%33s"), 
    lbg30 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    lbg = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), label = "기업규모코드", format.stata = "%10.0gc"), 
    bg = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    size = structure(c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""
    ), label = "기업규모명", format.stata = "%12s"), assets = structure(c(12150840320, 
    15652244480, 16448676864, 19630718976, 29004148736, 28329910272, 
    27457734656, 62851514368, 59374006272, 50737635328), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    liability = structure(c(54948823040, 66054799360, 81120837632, 
    106961879040, 122920968192, 140161728512, 162787033088, 159752404992, 
    149670641664, 105075081216), format.stata = "%9.0g"), sales = structure(c(88381997056, 
    102572998656, 114394996736, 119775002624, 128408002560, 134840000512, 
    143815000064, 141186007040, 136299003904, 138230005760), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    profit = structure(c(44432998400, 50231001088, 55298998272, 
    58389999616, 63920001024, 62578999296, 67171000320, 69623996416, 
    59872002048, 53057998848), format.stata = "%9.0g"), ebit = structure(c(19534999552, 
    19583000576, 21048999936, 21987000320, 25397999616, 23047999488, 
    21745000448, 26130999296, 23641999360, 1.458e+09), label = "Earning before interest and taxes (million won)", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    va = structure(c(25720190976, 32258500608, 35595018240, 34623062016, 
    41200451584, 43741118464, 48058458112, 50603368448, 70541492224, 
    22522920960), format.stata = "%9.0g"), va_pw = structure(c(26930000, 
    32920000, 36430000, 34010000, 41870000, 45090000, 49540000, 
    55730000, 88180000, 30440000), format.stata = "%9.0g"), va_ratio = structure(c(29.1000003814697, 
    31.4500007629395, 31.1200008392334, 28.9099998474121, 32.0900001525879, 
    32.439998626709, 33.4199981689453, 35.8400001525879, 51.75, 
    16.2900009155273), format.stata = "%9.0g"), k_productivity = structure(c(819.200012207031, 
    588.530029296875, 744.309997558594, 608.419982910156, 702.099975585938, 
    779.320007324219, 911.700012207031, 991.530029296875, 1964.06994628906, 
    502.309997558594), format.stata = "%9.0g"), k_productivity_gross = structure(c(31.4400005340576, 
    33.1300010681152, 29.6599998474121, 23.4799995422363, 25.0900001525879, 
    23.0799999237061, 22.5599994659424, 19.7700004577637, 26.2700004577637, 
    9.72999954223633), format.stata = "%9.0g"), wb = structure(c(8572080128, 
    9890159616, 10399187968, 12745639936, 14407654400, 15426884608, 
    17462267904, 16719245312, 14328732672, 15299931136), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    deprec = structure(c(1540752000, 1781939968, 2044096000, 
    2322487040, 2697072896, 3057124096, 3395273984, 1194128000, 
    1957659008, 2335313920), format.stata = "%9.0g"), cogs = structure(c(43948998656, 
    52342001664, 59095998464, 61384998912, 64488001536, 72260001792, 
    76643999744, 71562002432, 76427001856, 85172002816), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    land = structure(c(3962739968, 4533998080, 4673968128, 5412840960, 
    15167494144, 15234676736, 15215484928, 44340424704, 43726028800, 
    34115977216), format.stata = "%9.0g"), facilities = structure(c(5593545216, 
    6132070912, 7142042112, 8962248704, 9655307264, 9766675456, 
    9834147840, 12669279232, 12533188608, 12470169600), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    structures = structure(c(428073984, 439003008, 453208992, 
    453208992, 462492992, 487492992, 493648000, 298323008, 309323008, 
    352156992), format.stata = "%9.0g"), machinery = structure(c(7848509952, 
    12346684416, 13176728576, 15883726848, 18024470528, 20001619968, 
    5274594816, 20351035392, 21328994304, 25123174400), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    mold_pattern = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    machinery_heavy = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), format.stata = "%9.0g"), equipment = structure(c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), format.stata = "%9.0g"), devices = structure(c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), format.stata = "%9.0g")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `lbg30` of your data has only `0`, I modified half of those to `1`, where `df` is data you provided.

```
df1 <- df
df1$lbg30[6:10] <- 1
```

Then you may try

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(postcrisis = as.factor(postcrisis) %>% recode(., '0' = 'a', '1' = 'b'),
           lbg30 = as.factor(lbg30) %>% recode(., '0' = 'aaa', '1' = 'bbb'))  %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = lbg30, group = lbg30)) +
  
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = assets, color = "red")) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = liability, color = "blue")) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'the colour', 
                      values =c('blue'='blue','red'='red'), labels = c('liability','assets')) +
  facet_wrap(.~postcrisis)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks could you show me how to make a proper legend inside the plot? And instead of 0 and 1, can I put a proper label on the axis of bottom and top?

Comment: @joe I cannot response due to server maintain thing. You can change those `aaa` things to put labels, and edit `scale_colour_manual` part to your purpose. Please check the updated code and image above.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by proper legend but you can set the location of the legend using coordinates on an (0, 1) scale by adding `legend.position` to your plot's theme. For example `theme(legend.position = c(0.9, 0.1))` would put it around the bottom right corner inside the plot.

Comment: @Park, thanks again it is strange that whenever I run your code I got the following error message    Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `postcrisis`.
ℹ `postcrisis = as.factor(postcrisis) %>% recode(., `0` = "Pre crisis", `1` = "Post crisis")`.
x unused arguments (`0` = "Pre crisis", `1` = "Post crisis") Can you figure out what's going on here? Sorry for grey blurs and missing double quote signs it is because it automatically transform double quotes into grey blurs.

Comment: @joe It's really hard to find out the reason with that error that it's quotes looks weird. Can you add screenshot of that error/code to your question?

Comment: @Park, I just added. thanks for the response. I only changed the variable names.